# How is react hydrate implemented?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

According to the docs, when React.hydrateRoot is called with a particular DOM element, React will "attempt to attach event listeners to the existing markup and take over rendering the app on the client." How is this implemented? It seems to me like "attach" might be a bit of a misnomer, React components and event listeners are pure JS which output a virtual DOM, and the React Virtual DOM state is compared to the actual DOM state to intelligently apply diffs and update the page.

Is the only difference between react hydration and a normal render is that it uses the DOM in the provided container as the initial state to compare the virtual DOM against (allowing the initial page render to happen before react logic is executed)? If so why don't the docs say something like "uses prerendered DOM state to perform initial diffs with Virtual DOM", seems like this would be a more clear explanation about what hydrate actually does.